# How to change the color of a certain print line in command prompt with python?

Tags: python, cmd, colors, format

Is there a way to **change** the **color** or **style** of a certain print line in CMD with Python?

I want to change the color of text directly in CMD with *python commands*.

I've tried :

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

print(Fore.RED + 'This text is red in color')

print("\033[1;32m This text is Bright Green  \n")


from colored import fg
print ('%s Hello World !!! %s' % (fg(1), attr(0)))
```

but none of it works. They just open a new window for a short period of time.

Comment: That sounds like you're launching the script from, for example, your file manager. You'll see a command window pop up, run the script, and then close once the script finishes. That's just how Windows works, nothing to do with Python or colorama. Try launching your script from an existing command window.

Comment: Note: `\033[1;32m` is a specific sequence for few specific terminals. In short: do not do it. Use a general library which select the right code for the actual terminal. (or people which will use your script inside other scripts will hate you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `init()` command from `colorama`

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, init

init()

print(Fore.RED + 'This text is red in color')

print("\033[1;32mThis text is Bright Green  \n")
```

[Colorama Help](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)

Then run the python script from the CMD, some thing like this

`C:\...>colouredText.py`

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This one works after installing colorama with 'pip install colorama'